# Is there an extra memory limitation for component IO

Tags: openmdao

Is there an extra memory limitation for component IO or partials that is imposed by openMDAO?

I can see that only 12 % of the whole memory is used but  i still get such an error. Is this python or openMDAO related cap?

```
....
    self.run_driver()
  File "\Anaconda3\envs\py36_test\lib\site-packages\openmdao-2.3.1-py3.6.egg\openmdao\core\problem.py", line 494, in run_driver
    self.final_setup()
  File "\Anaconda3\envs\py36_test\lib\site-packages\openmdao-2.3.1-py3.6.egg\openmdao\core\problem.py", line 625, in final_setup
    force_alloc_complex=self._force_alloc_complex)
  File "\Anaconda3\envs\py36_test\lib\site-packages\openmdao-2.3.1-py3.6.egg\openmdao\core\system.py", line 786, in _final_setup
   self._setup_partials(recurse=recurse)
  File "\Anaconda3\envs\py36_test\lib\site-packages\openmdao-2.3.1-py3.6.egg\openmdao\core\group.py", line 1802, in _setup_partials
    subsys._setup_partials(recurse)
  File "\Anaconda3\envs\py36_test\lib\site-packages\openmdao-2.3.1-py3.6.egg\openmdao\core\group.py", line 1802, in _setup_partials
    subsys._setup_partials(recurse)
  File "\Anaconda3\envs\py36_test\lib\site-packages\openmdao-2.3.1-py3.6.egg\openmdao\core\explicitcomponent.py", line 68, in _setup_partials
    super(ExplicitComponent, self)._setup_partials()
  File "\Anaconda3\envs\py36_test\lib\site-packages\openmdao-2.3.1-py3.6.egg\openmdao\core\component.py", line 306, in _setup_partials
  self._declare_partials(of, wrt, dependent=dependent, rows=rows, cols=cols, val=val)
  File "\Anaconda3\envs\py36_test\lib\site-packages\openmdao-2.3.1-py3.6.egg\openmdao\core\component.py", line 894, in _declare_partials
   meta['value'] = np.zeros(shape)
MemoryError
```

Answer (score 0):

there isn't enough detail to provide a good answer to this question, but when you hit memory errors its maybe because you're using 32 bit python?